# Python: Object Oriented Programming

Tags: python-2.7

How do you declare an empty list as a member of the constructor function in a python class ?

Eg:

```
class House:
    def __init__(self):
        self.genome = []
        for i in range(0, 4):
            self.genome.append(1)

s = House
print s.genome()
```

I keep getting the error: class home has no attribute 'genome' ?
Thank You.

Comment: `s = House` assigns the _class_ to s. `s = House()` with the parens makes a new _instance_ and assigns that to s.

Comment: If you are learning Python from scratch do yourself a favour and start with version 3.6, 2.7 is being phased out.

Comment: Also `genome` would be a list, which isn't callable.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is ok. You just have a problem with how you call it:

```
>>> class House:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.genome = []
...         for i in range(0, 4):
...             self.genome.append(1)
...
>>> s=House()
>>> s.genome
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```